# How can I prevent applications sending data over the net without my consent?

Tags: networking, firewall, privacy

Recently I had a couple of instances of programs sending data (copies of some of my config files) out over the net.  I consider this very bad form on behalf of the writers, and I want to prevent it happening in future.

One example was a program that had a command line diagnostic utility.  When I ran it, it immediately gathered up a bunch of info, not only the program's own config, but the system as well, and uploaded them to a server. Some of those files might have contained data like usernames and passwords.

So, like in Windows, I would like a program that warns me when another program tries to send data, or even initiate communication over the net, without my knowledge.  Ideally then I can whitelist only the programs I want to allow to do this, and the rest will be prevented by default.

Edit:  I found a web page from 2007 that talks about this [here](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/application-wise-network-filtering-on-linux/)

They mention three programs (Systrace, Tuxguardian and Program Guard) that used to exist, but I suspect cannot be used with the new kernels and distributions like Ubuntu any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a simple, non-technical solution. That said, if you're willing to get your hands dirty, read on.

Ubuntu uses a permissions framework called [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), in which each application has a "profile" that defines what it is allowed to do. If you have administrator privileges, you can edit AppArmor profiles to allow applications on your system to do less. You can also create restrictive profiles for binaries that don't have them. Profiles are stored in `/etc/apparmor.d/`.

You'll want to read the [AppArmor Profile Language Guide](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/QuickProfileLanguage) and [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor). In essence, however, you want to remove all `network` permissions, and then put all profiles into "complain" mode so you know when they're trying to do networking with:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

Comment: That is good news.  I was led to believe that AppArmour would need a profile for each app, and that new apps would have full access by default.  What you describe sounds like it might work.  I will try it out.

Comment: On second reading, it still seems like new programs will have full access until a profile exists.  I would have to create a new profile for each and every binary, and I may not even know or understand what comes with a package and what it might do. Worse, some packages come with profiles of their own which will allow them to do whatever they were programmed to do.

Comment: You can glob match (eg write a profile for `/usr/bin/*) for `deny`ing.

Comment: I have read up on profiles and have found that "deny rules are evaluated before allow rules and cannot be overridden by an allow rule".  So doesn't this mean that a /usr/bin/* rule denying network access will stop ALL my apps, even those with profiles allowing it, from using the network?

Comment: Hm, I did not know that. One workaround would be to use deny rules on `/usr/bin/`, then move all binaries you want to have network access to another prefix (like `/usr/netbin/`) and add that to your `$PATH` variable. This would, of course, screw up your package manager updates though... huh. Alternatively, is it possible to use `$GLOBIGNORE` in profiles maybe?

Comment: It would be good if $GLOBIGNORE worked inside apparmor, but maybe not as there is a proposed addition to globbing inside apparmor that would help. E.g. /etc/{*^shadow} is the same as allowing everything /etc/* matches except /etc/shadow .  My 'whitelist' would be all the apps I add to the exception list.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thanks, even though I am not sure yet that it's the way I want to go.  It's a pity that previous projects to do this have been abandoned.